# iPython ImportError: No module named display

Tags: python, import

Trying to run python script but can't find module IPython.display.. Seems like it would be something simple but I can't find an answer anywhere!

```
/vagrant/dreamify.py in <module>()
      4 import scipy.ndimage as nd
      5 import PIL.Image
----> 6 from IPython.display import clear_output, Image, display
      7 from google.protobuf import text_format
      8

ImportError: No module named display
```

Comment: What version of IPython do you have?

Comment: vagrant@precise32:/vagrant$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Jun 22 2015, 19:43:34)
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the [IPython's repository](https://github.com/ipython/ipython), the `IPython.display` module was added in commit [5462c7e](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/commit/5462c7efd6027ae36a2c89e369e82ba6d4eb76bf), and it was released with IPython 0.13.

I think you have an older version of IPython.

You can check the IPython version with `ipython --version`.

It can be upgraded with `pip install --upgrade IPython`.

Comment: After attempting this it is telling me that my version of IPython is 4.0.0.

    pip install --upgrade IPython
"Requirement already up-to-date..."

Comment: Which IPython did you updated? The one from the vagrant's VM or your host's ipython? Or try checking which IPython module it's using e.g. `ipython -c "import IPython as i;print i"` and check if a `display.py` file exists in the same directory as the `__init__.pyc`.

Answer (score 0):

In Pycharm import module ipython. In Pycharm go to preferences and then project interpreter. Click on the "+" sign then search ipython and install package.